# How to handle very similar buttons without using one function for each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, append

I have a bunch of anchor links where I use javascript to fade in different divs to mimic pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    showHomePage();

    $('.homebutton').click(function() {
        displayNone();
        showWindow("homepage");
    } );
    $('.aboutbutton').click(function() {
        displayNone();
        showWindow("aboutpage");
    } );
    $('.gallerybutton').click(function() {
        displayNone();
        showWindow("gallerypage");
    } );
    $('.musicbutton').click(function() {
        displayNone();
        showWindow("musicpage");
    } );

    function displayNone() {
        $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(0);
    }

    function showHomePage() {
        $('.pagecontainer').fadeIn();
        $('#homepage').fadeIn();
    }

    function showWindow(name) {
        $('#' + name).fadeIn();
    }

});
```

```
<body>
....
....
<a href="#homepage" class="homebutton">Home</a>
<a href="#aboutpage" class="aboutbutton">About</a>
<a href="#gallerypage" class="gallerybutton">Gallery</a>
<a href="#musicpage" class="musicbutton">Music</a>
....
....
<div id="homepage">Home page</div>
<div id="aboutpage">About page</div>
<div id="gallerypage">Gallery page</div>
<div id="musicpage">Music page</div>
....
</body>
```

All pages are set to hidden at first (alpha=0), and when the link is clicked any page currently displayed is set to hidden with displayNone() and the corresponding page fades in. This all works with no problem.

But I want to shorten this code. As you can see if I have say 50 pages, the javascript portion will get very messy as I have to write pretty much the same line 50 times. All my links have the class "**_button" which corresponds to "**_page", so I think there should be a shortcut to this which only needs one function? Something like:

- When [class name] is clicked, delete the "button" part of the class name
- Then append "page" to the end of the name
- For example when "aboutbutton" is clicked, change the name to "about", then add "page", which becomes "aboutpage"
- Then display that div

But I'm not sure how to write this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to look into jQuery string manipulation and you're golden. Your logic is reasonable.

Comment: Are you able to change your IDs and classes, or are the pages already built?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have multiple classes in HTML, so your buttons could be like this:

```
<a href="#homepage" class="button homebutton">Home</a>
<a href="#aboutpage" class="button aboutbutton">About</a>
<a href="#gallerypage" class="button gallerybutton">Gallery</a>
<a href="#musicpage" class="button musicbutton">Music</a>
```

Then use a single event handler to target them all. This should get you started:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Luckly, your urls match the id selectors
    // do not use this.href, as it will return the full, resolved url
    // (see Kolink's answer)
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function() {
    $(".pagecontainer>div").fadeOut(0);
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();
  });
  $(".pagecontainer").fadeIn();
  $("#homepage").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: I'm curious about your use of `getAttribute`, will `this.href` fail in any browser?

Comment: `this.href` will result in something like `http://example.com/path/to/current/page.html#homepage` - in other words, it returns the fully resolved, absolute URL. `getAttribute`, however, will return the literal attribute in the source.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that. Will update my answer.